# Is it possible to get Query AsyncApiBatch in salesforce (in SOQL)

Tags: bulk-api

Is it possible to get Query AsyncApiBatch in salesforce (in SOQL), I am trying to get this information so that external app could understand how many batches are consumed in last 24 hours and how many are remaining.

Object Prefix for object is - 751
API Name is - AsyncApiBatch

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncApiBatch object is not queryable, however AsyncApexJob is. The AsyncApexJob object is the data that we see in Setup->Monitoring->ApexJobs

However the following query should give the equivalent that you need:

```
SELECT SUM(JobItemsProcessed) 
FROM AsyncApexJob
WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
```

Additionaly you may wish to filter on particular JobTypes or MethodNames

Comment: do we get BULK Api request in this query ?

Comment: No, some terminology overlap.. I am referring to Apex Batches not Bulk Api Batches, I don't see a way to query with soql. Assume you have seen the docs: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm#CSHID=asynch_api_batches_monitor.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fasynch_api_batches_monitor.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its not a answer in that case then.